# Generate a new table entry in one sheet from another

Tags: numbers

I have a numbers file with 2 sheets: **sheet1** and **sheet2**.

On **sheet1** is where I am entering some data in some cells.
On **sheet2** there is a `transactions` table with different entries.

Is it possible to have a *button* or *something* in **sheet1**, where I can enter some information in some cells **sheet1**, and when I press that *button*, it adds a new entry in the `transactions` table in **sheet2** with some values from **sheet1**?

Its straight forward to use values from one sheet into another by using a format like `SHEETNAME::TABLENAME::CELL` in a formula, but I don't know how I can (or if I can) achieve the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like iOS has this feature under the names of `Forms`, just like you add a sheet, you can add a Form for a table. Don't have it on the Mac App, but that seems to be it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to enter data into Sheet 1 and have it populate in a "transactions" table in Sheet 2? Surely a "Transactions" table would be where you enter the data in first as a source, and everything else reads off of that?

What are you entering in that aren't transactions?